# Will a pre-compiled asp.net website's performance be affected if it's virtual root folder has static files

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

I have a **pre-compiled** ASP.NET website on staging environment. It's virtual root folder contains a folder called _release that contains **lots of zipped up backup files**. Each of these zip files basically serve as a snapshot of the previous releases.

I will surely move those outside the root folder, if the website was not pre-compiled. Was wondering if the same reasoning would hold good even if the website was pre-compiled?

Would ASP.NET or IIS performance be slow or taxed due to the presence of these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much performance that would concern me, but the possiblity of somebody finding these files and downloading copies of your codebase.  There's no real need for these to be available here at all, and should probably be removed.